# try to style the progress bar bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to style progress in bootstrap3 like this

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria- valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
    border:solid yellow;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.progress-bar{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

when i executed, it leave like border bottom with grey color inside progress-bar.
how to remove it?

Comment: sir, your progress-bar didnt have border color and background color yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `box-shadow: none;` to `.progress-bar`

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6LgL4Lh/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap sets `box-shadow` by default, so you have to remove it manually. See: https://jsfiddle.net/1003ottc/

```
.progress{
    border:solid yellow;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.progress-bar{
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```